# Подключение ojdbc

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbc

Не могу подключить драйвер.
Скачал файл ojdbc8.jar
Указал в CLASSPATH путь до папки, в которой находится файл

Выполняю этот код:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class SqlExamples{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        String username = "user";
        String password = "pass";
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.31.65.28:1521:l10";
        //DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, username, password);
            System.out.println(connection);
            }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("SSS");
        }



    }


}
```

Получаю ошибки:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>
> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
> java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
> java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
> SqlExamples.main(SqlExamples.java:16)

Как проверить, что действительно драйвер установлен правильно и работает ли он?

Answer (score 0):

1. В classpath надо указывать не папку в которой лежит jar файл, а непосредственно сам jar файл.
2. В IDEA добавьте jar файл в свойствах проекта (Project Structure) в Libraries.